# sqlplus adding column heading

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I'm using sqlplus from oracle and trying to figure out the way to create a customer list and categorize them based on the following criteria:

- if the # of Account is 1 then categorize them as "Entry Level"
- if the # of Account is 2-3 then categorize them as "Growing"
- if the # of Account is more than 4 then categorize them as "Mature"

then creating a expected output (which I have attached as an image).

[image: expected output]

I also have attached ERD for this.

This is what I have so far.

```
SELECT DISTINCT first_name "First",
                surname "Last",
                customer_number "Cust #",
                account_type "# of Accts"
  FROM (  SELECT first_name,
                 surname,
                 customer_number,
                 account_type
            FROM wgb_customer
                 JOIN wgb_account USING (customer_number)
                 JOIN wgb_account_type USING (account_type)
        ORDER BY account_type);
```

please help!
This is expected output!

```
First       Last        Cust#         # of Accts     Level
----------------------------------------------------------------        
Peter      Chen         2566217             3         Growing           
Byron      Griffith     1113004             1         Entry Level
Patricia   Lee          9871332             1         Entry Level
Henri      Poincare     1113501             3         Growing   
John       Synge        1112401             2         Growing
```

Comment: Please add sample data and expected output to your question, as tabular text. As it is, your query does not make a lot of sense.

Comment: Right, but tabular text is more readable for most of us. Also, would you please add sample data as well ?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know how to do tabular text, so I just did my best to make expected output as a text lol

Comment: Please add **sample data and expected output** to your question. See [this Meta StackExchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81852/172661) for help posting tabular data.

Comment: Thanks for expected output. But we are still missing the sample data, can you provide that ?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like aggregation with a `case` expression:

```
select c.first_name, c.surname, c.customer_number,
       count(*) as num_accounts,
       (case when count(*) = 1 then 'Entry Level'
             when count(*) <= 3 then 'Growing'
             else 'Mature'
        end) as level
from wgb_customer c join
     wgb_account a
     using (customer_number) 
group by c.first_name, c.surname, c.customer_number;
```